# experienced in VS experience with VS with experience in

Tags: grammar, american-english, nuance

I wonder how to improve my sentence more intuitive in English.
I want to say 1) I am a Designer.  2) I have experience in(or with) Websites Design. 3) I researched to design the sites.

Could you please help me? I wrote 3 below sentences.

1) He is an **experienced** Designer in Web sites **utilizing** research.

2) He is an **experienced** Designer with Web sites **by** researching.

3) He is a Designer **with experience in** Websites **using** research.

Comment: First, this is off-topic proofreading: you must tell us what you think is wrong because we are not a proofreading service. Second, the first sentence is borderline ungrammatical, while the last one is most natural but still terrible. That's because lastly and most importantly, you should **never, ever, *ever*** use the word *utilizing*. It’s just an overblown many-syllabled synonym for *using* that alerts the careful reader to the pretentious wordiness of its author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more concise alternative sentence with the same set of parameters.
**"He is an experienced Web Site Designer who *utilizes topical* research."** *topical; (of a subject) of immediate relevance, interest, or importance owing to its relation to current events.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. :)
How about if you want to say more than Web Site Design.

**"He is an experienced Designer in Web Site and e-commerce utilizing design research and technology."**

Can you help me with this sentence, please?

Comment: You handled that nicely by yourself.

Comment: @Sue if you think the answer was helpful, consider accepting the answer.